The usage of respectively, when explaining something in maths ( maths report)
Does this make sense/ where could improve it??
Total perimeter = (a1 + b1 +c1) + (b2 + c2) +...+ (b15 + c15)
With 'a' being the previous hypotenuse (radius), respectively. Hence why it doesn't appear in the above equation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why do you need to use "respectively"? Ideally you should use subscripts for the numbers, use n for an arbitrary subscript, and explain what all the terms mean - maybe it's obvious, but we don't know the context and what you have already defined.

If you use respectively then it must refer to two or more things. A typical definition from the Cambridge Dictionary is:

In a way that relates or belongs to each of the separate people or
things you have just mentioned:
In the 200 metres, Lizzy and Sarah came first and third respectively (= Lizzy won the race and Sarah was third).
Steven and James are aged 10 and 13 respectively.

Your example only mentions one item "a" so "respectively" should be omitted ("why" is unnecessary as well).

With 'a' being the previous hypotenuse (radius). Hence it doesn't appear in the above equation.

Or you could say (in a different context where it was true)

With 'a' and 'b' being the previous radii respectively. Hence they
don't appear in the above equation.


thanks, this was very helpful
